# Facebook OAuth redirect shows FB image/link instead of authorization page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a perl CGI script doing the Facebook authorization flow as described at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/.  When I go to my Facebook app page in a browser my script receives the initial query from Facebook, authenticates the signed_request, and then sends a redirect to the following url:

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=NNN&scope=[...]&display=page&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmydomain.com%3A8080%2Fperl%2Fdev%2Ffb.pl%3Fcallback%3D1

The redirect_uri is what I have defined as my Web Site in the app config, and it gets accepted just fine.  But what the browser then shows is a big Facebook logo image and a link below it, both of which go to:

http://www.facebook.com/connect/uiserver.php?display=page&next=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.facebook.com%2Foauth%2Fauthorize_success%3Fredirect_uri%3D[...]

When I click on that I get what I want, the "Request for Permission" page asking the user to authorize the app.  Everything proceeds normally from there.

So why am I getting that initial FB logo page instead of going directly to the authorization page?

Comment: How do you execute the redirect to the Facebook authorization URI?

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your comment.  I just do "print $query->redirect($url);" where $url is above and $query is the CGI query.

Answer (score 1):

Someone answered this over in the Facebook forum (http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=290957#p290957), ironically with a reference back to another question here.  You just need to do a client-side redirect using javascript, so the output of your CGI script should look like:

```
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 344

<script>top.location="https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=[...]";</script>
```